# Processor system synchronization?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, clocks

Processor has the internal clock which is a multiplier of the main clock which is present on the motherboard which is designed by keeping in mind the critical path and the slowest device on board,

My question is :-

How there are two clocks working simultaneously in the computer system, what is the mechanism of their working, We know the processor is the one which is executing the instructions and then send the relevant signal out to the other components for any read or write operations. Processor runs at different clock and lets suppose it executes a read instruction to get some data from the memory in its one of registers and next instruction is to use that data for any ALU operations if the processor runs on different clock and rest of the system runs at different clock, doesn't make it any conflict ?  I know there is a concept of wait state, is it in the hand of programmer or hardware designer ?

Comment: Look to the right, and to the left. The two people you see work (think) at different clock speeds (quickness of thought) than you. Maybe one is slower, and one is faster. However to you communicate?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Raphael I will read it, but I didnt get the first part like, Left or Right ?

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71621/how-does-multi-core-cpu-implement-asynchronous-coordination) quite a while back on electronics.stackexchange

Comment: @Billiska I saw this question but your question is related to multicore system how can we relate it to this scenerio

Comment: Right, it seems your question concern "the current practice" of the matter rather than "the theoretical ways it could be done". (because you mention you already how wait state could help in theory) Maybe you want to make it more clear in your question? (And to help people who know the current practice identify the point of your question quicker)

Comment: Its not specifically concern the current practice, your question is related to multicore and my question is specifically related to the clock handling while dealing with memory of different speeds ?